# Condensing tuple of tuple of tuples of tuples of... into a list of reduced items

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools, iterable-unpacking

I have an iterable with a lot of nesting - not always to equal depth, but guarantees that each element of the original is at least once-iterable - I define this in the block quote below.

> An item is more than once iterable if all its elements are iterable.
> An item is once iterable if none of its elements are iterable
> An item is twice iterable if its elements are iterables of non iterable elements, e.g. `((1,),(1,2,),(1,2,3,))` is twice iterable

Below, I have a few examples of these such iterables that I consider to be input.

```py
trie_like= ( ((((('a','b','c','d'),), (('a','b','c','e'),),), ((('a','b','d','e'),),),), (((('a','c','d','e'),),),),), ((((('b','c','d','e'),),),),), )
uneven = (((1,),(2,),(3,)),((1,2,3),), (12,34),)
```

I aim to write function that reduces the level of nesting such that each element in the condensed iterable is a tuple that is *once* iterable. That is to say the function unnests to the nearest twice iterable object.

```py
trie_like_condensed = (('a','b','c','d'),('a','b','c','e'),('a','b','d','e'), ('a','c','d','e'),('b','c','d','e'),)
uneven_condensed = ((1,),(2,),(3,),(1,2,3),(12,34),)
```

I thought I might be able to repeatedly call itertools.chain.from_iterable on it tuple until I can map it, but I can't quite get the end condition right.

```py
import itertools
from collections.abc import Iterable

t = ( ((((('a','b','c','d'),), (('a','b','c','e'),),), ((('a','b','d','e'),),),), (((('a','c','d','e'),),),),), ((((('b','c','d','e'),),),),),)

count = 0 # just to avoid inf loops
while isinstance(t,Iterable) and count<20:
    count = count + 1
    t,p = itertools.tee(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t))
    print(list(p))
print(*map("".join, t))
```

For this I think I've got the depth query wrong, AND it would only work for the variable I called `trie_like` which has depth 4 at every deepest tuple. I thought maybe then I could use something like `itertools.takewhile` but I also can't get that to work, my attempt below.

```py
def unnest_iterables(t,count=0):
    iter_part = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: isinstance(x,Iterable),t)
    niter_part = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: not isinstance(x,Iterable),t)
    # rest of t processed by recursion
    iter_part,p = itertools.tee(iter_part)
    niter_part,pn = itertools.tee(niter_part)
    print(f'Depth = {count}: {list(p)} : {list(pn)}')
    if count > 10:
        print('TEST: Big oof')
        return []
    if iter_part is None or niter_part is None:
        return itertools.chain(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter_part),niter_part)
    try:
        return unnest_iterables(itertools.chain(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter_part),niter_part),count+1)
    except StopIteration:
        return itertools.chain(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter_part),niter_part)




t = ( (((((1,2,3,4),), ((1,2,3,5),),), (((1,2,4,5),),),), ((((1,3,4,5),),),),), (((((2,3,4,5),),),),),)
t = ( (((((1,2,3,4),), ((1,2,3,5),),), (((1,2,4,5),),),), ((((1,3,4,5),),),),), ((((2,3,4,5),),),),)
print(*unnest_iterables(t))
```

Comment: I am still not clear what your goal is. I suppose the example named `t` is the input data. And you want to convert it to...what exactly? Could you provide an example of the output?

Comment: The solution from @IoeCmcomc is good, unless there are edge cases unspecified in your original examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample input and output, you only need to collect all once-iterable items in the input and put them into a tuple, which make the output a twice-iterable tuple. This can be achieved without the `itertools` module:

```
def is_once_iterable(items: tuple):
    return any(not isinstance(item, tuple) for item in items)

# Collect all once-iterable items and put them into a list
def _simplify_nesting(items: tuple, condensed: list):
    if is_once_iterable(items):
        condensed.append(items)
        return

    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            _simplify_nesting(item, condensed)

# Wrapper function for _simplify_nesting
def simplify_nesting(items: tuple):
    condensed = []
    _simplify_nesting(items, condensed)
    return tuple(condensed)

inp = (((1,),(2,),(3,)),((1,2,3),), (12,34),) 
print(simplify_nesting(inp)) # ((1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2, 3), (12, 34))
```